# Term for a payment paid by an insurance firm to an insured party

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Insurance terminology: what do we call the payment that an insurance firm pays a beneficiary if the terms of an insurance policy are met?

For example - in life insurance, in case an insured party dies, the beneficiaries receive a one-time payment. Or in case a claim is made by someone with homeowner's insurance on hurricane damage.

Yes, "payment" could work here- but I use this throughout to refer to the actual payments made by the insurance companies customers (the premiums). Is there a term for payments made by the company?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for **Insurance indemnification** that refers to the the payment of an **indemnity** in compensation for a particular loss ?

Answer (score 1):

*Benefit* is the usual term. It is often qualified by a term designating the particular character of the payout; in the life insurance industry, for example, the payout is usually called the *death benefit*.

*Indemnity* is often used in technical discussion of policies which pay some proportion of a holder's actual loss.

Comment: In my experience in the UK, life companies refer to the *death benefit* when describing a policy. When it comes to actual payment they will talk of *paying a claim*. That applies to most types of insurance. *No sooner had insurers paid his first claim, than another of his buildings went up in smoke*.

Comment: @WS2 In the US, too, the term *benefit* is used mostly prospectively, particularly when it is necessary to distinguish this from the cash value of the policy. *Paying the claim* is the ordinary language for describing the payout when it is made.